# How to search database with dynamically created query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2

I would like to start from an example: you received some list with needed fields. This list may vary and even if it is empty, select all fields. This list can include fields from several tables. Is there any way to generate SELECT query for doing this?

Probably there is a way, but it will look like parsing received list, adding appropriate table alias, and then adding modified list into select clause. Is it best way actually?

**Update 1**

- The goal is only to get passed fields from several tables, not to
  control result from any of them(its about first answer)

Comment: You need to dynamically build a query based on the search information you have. It's hard to provide a proper answer without any specifics, or unless you can narrow it down to a specific problem.

Comment: I only wanted to ask if there is better solution than mine. Not encountering any other problems at the moment

Comment: You don't tell us which is your solution so that we can tell you alternatives.

Comment: My solution at the moment is parsing fields list and create query for it. I thought that there is some better ways to do it(some existing library or so)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a query that first selects dynamically fields, depending on your criteria.

for example lets assume you have two criteria passed to you. Then (after you have made sure your criteria1 and criteria2 are safe):

```
$mySelect = '';      //placeholder so that you can add select fields
$extraTables = '';   //placeholder to put the extra tables I may need
$criteria = " WHERE 1 ";    //this will select everything
if ($criteria1>'') {
  $mySelect .= ' , t3.field3 '; 
  $extraTables = " , aDifferentTable AS t3";
  $criteria .= " AND t3.someKey = t1.someKey '";
  $criteria .= " AND field_crit1 = '" . $criteria1 . "'";
}

//and an example of connecting dynamically to an other table
if ($criteria2>'') {
  $mySelect .= ' , t2.field5 '; 
  $extraTables = " , anOtherTable AS t2";
  $criteria .= " AND t2.someKey = t1.someKey '";
  $criteria .= " AND t2.field_crit2 = '" . $criteria2 . "'";
}

//lets combine all together into one dynamically created query    
$myquery = "SELECT t1.something " . $mySelect . " FROM myTable  AS t1";   

$myquery = $myqury . $extraTables . $criteria;
```